# Unable to start Kestrel on macOS Monterey

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, kestrel, macos-monterey

I upgrade my `macOS Big Sur` to `macOS Monterey` then I try to run my .Net Core app with `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000` config it gives me error as below

```
2021-10-27 19:23:25.0068|FATAL|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Unable to start Kestrel.
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:5000: address already in use.
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use
```

when I try find who listen the port `5000` with codes as below

```
sudo lsof -nP -i:5000 | grep LISTEN
```

results are;

```
ControlCe 2874 sametcelikbicak   17u  IPv4 0xac23fd083a725c89      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
ControlCe 2874 sametcelikbicak   18u  IPv6 0xac23fd082e8a6671      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
```

then I try to kill that listen with kill command as below

```
kill -9 2874
```

that port listen does not kill, I run `sudo lsof -nP -i:5000 | grep LISTEN` again to test it but it gave me that result again

```
ControlCe 4271 sametcelikbicak   17u  IPv4 0xac23fd0849ef2c59      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
ControlCe 4271 sametcelikbicak   18u  IPv6 0xac23fd083995b411      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
```

if I try `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5001` to run .Net Core app it works, also I restart my mac but still gives error, why `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000` config does not work with `Monterey` and who always use the port `5000`

Also my dotnet version and sdk-list as below

```
➜  ~ dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.504 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.201 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.102 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.103 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
➜  ~ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
➜  ~ dotnet --version
5.0.300
➜  ~
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `why ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000 config does not work with Monterey?` - because as you already found, port 5000 is in use. `and who always use the port 5000?` - a quick search shows it to be [AirPlay in the Control Center](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332). Either disable that setting or use a different port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@devNull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5803406/devnull), [AirPlay in the Control Center](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332) solutions fixed my problem.

Basic steps of the solutions;

Goto to System Preferences > Sharing > Uncheck **`AirPlay Receiver`**